# How to run all "N take 2" iterations of a function?

Tags: r

I've written a simple correlation function that takes in three variables.  "A" and "B" are numerical vectors of equal length, and "n" is the length.

```
Corr.fxn <- function(A, B, n){
Correlation <- (sum((A - mean(A))*(B - mean(B))) / (n-1)) / (sd(A)*sd(B))
return(Correlation)
}
```

The function works well enough, but I have many vectors I want to process. What's the best way to modify this code to process all "N take 2" unique analyses for my set of vectors "N"?

EDIT:

Example data showing the structure of the vectors:

```
A <- c(-1, 0, 1, -1, 0, 1, -1, 0, 1)
B <- c(1, 1, -1, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 1)
...
n <- length(A)
```

So let's say I have vectors A through Z and I want to modify my code to output a new vector containing all {26 take 2} correlation values.

Comment: How are the vectors organized? Making up some example input data and posting is going to be useful.

Comment: `apply(combn(N, 2), 2, Corr.fxn)`? If `N` is a list, index it instead.

Comment: *"N take 2"* makes me think of [`combn`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/combn.html). If you do something like `combn(N, 2, simplify = FALSE)`, you'll get a list where each element is a list of two of your `N` vectors. Try `combn(list(1:2, 3:4, 5:6), 2, simplify = FALSE)` as an example. (You beat me to the punch, alistaire ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible way you can do it assuming you have a bunch of numeric vectors in a list `v` as follows:

```
v <- list()
for (i in 1:10) {
  v[[i]] <- sample(1:10, 10, replace = TRUE)
}

apply(combn(1:10, 2), 2, function(x) Corr.fxn(v[[x[1]]], v[[x[2]]], length(v[[x[1]]])))
```

Answer (score 1):

In this answer, I assume 2 things. First, you want to write a function yourself, since otherwise you can use `Hmisc::rcorr`. Second, you want the "N take 2" part to be inside the function, otherwise the ways suggested earlier are correct. In that case, you can do this:

```
Corr.fxn <- function(vectors, n){
    pairs<- combn(length(vectors), 2)
    npairs<- ncol(pairs)
    cor.mat<- matrix(NA, nrow = length(vectors), ncol = npairs)
    for (i in 1:ncol(pairs)){
        A<- vectors[[pairs[1, i]]]
        B<- vectors[[pairs[2, i]]]
    cor.mat[pairs[1, i], pairs[2, i]] <- (sum((A - mean(A))*(B - mean(B))) / (n-1)) /(sd(A)*sd(B))
    }
    cor.mat[lower.tri(cor.mat)]<- cor.mat[upper.tri(cor.mat)] ###
    diag(cor.mat)<- 1 ###
    cor.mat<- data.frame(cor.mat) ###
    row.names(cor.mat)<- colnames(cor.mat)<- names(vectors) ###
    return(cor.mat)
}
```

The lines that end in `###` are there for decorative reasons. The main input is a list called "vectors". So it works as follows:

```
A<- runif(100, 1, 100)
B<- runif(100, 30, 50)
C<- runif(100, 120, 200)
> Corr.fxn(list(A=A, B=B, C=C), n=100)
           A           B           C
A  1.0000000 -0.11800104 -0.13980458
B -0.1180010  1.00000000  0.04933581
C -0.1398046  0.04933581  1.00000000
```